# Hyperlink chart bars using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I am using the D3 toolkit to create a stacked bar graph of some data.  I want link the bars  to a separate page with more detail about the underlying data for that bar.  I can't figure out how to turn the bars into hyperlinks.  
The code below is based on a [demo](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208)  that I have been tinkering with.  When I inspect the code in Google Chrome it looks correct but the bars aren't clickable. 
 Tremendous thanks in advance for ideas and suggestions on this!

Source, attempting to add link to Google to each bar:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="d3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("./data.csv", function(error, data) {
  color.domain(d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) { return key !== "State"; }));

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    var y0 = 0;
    d.ages = color.domain().map(function(name) { return {name: name, y0: y0, y1: y0 += +d[name]}; });
    d.total = d.ages[d.ages.length - 1].y1;
  });

  data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.total - a.total; });

  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Population");

  var state = svg.selectAll(".state")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "g")
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "http://www.google.com"; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.State) + ",0)"; });

  state.selectAll("rect")
      .data(function(d) { return d.ages; })
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y1); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y1); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

    state.append("a")
    .attr("xlink:href", "http://www.google.com")
    ;

  var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(color.domain().slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can add "a" html mark in SVG.

But you can add an event on each bar segment:

```
state.on('click',function(d){
  ... some great code ...
})
```